# Не парсит кириллицу PHP

Tags: php, парсер

Есть PHP парсер на библиотеке DiDOM. Настроен был на одном тестовом сервере, работал. Сейчас перенесен на другом, и там почему то не парсит значение с кириллицей.

Теряюсь в догадках, почему такое происходит. Интересно было бы услышать подсказку, в сторону каких настроек смотреть. Подозреваю, что php, но что конкретно?...

```
<?php

$start = microtime(true);

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use DiDom\Document;

$document = new Document('http://donor.ru/catalog/tovar/', true);

//  H1
    $main_heading = $document->find('.c_name')[0]->text();

//  Текущая дата
    $date_res = date("mdYHis");

//  Фото        
    $foto = $document->find('.gallerylayer img::attr(src)')[0];
    $foto_full = ("https://donor.ru$foto");
    $foto_name = "id1$date_res.jpg";
    copy ( $foto_full, "/fotodir/$foto_name" );

//  Цена    
    $price = $document->find('.c_price')[0];
    $price_result = preg_replace('/[^\d]+/', '', $price);
//  Бренд
    $brand = $document->find('.item_info_section')[0]->first('dl')->xpath('//dt//strong')[0]->text();
//  Состав в % для вывода
    $sostav = $document->find('.c_mix')[0]->text();
//  Состав без % для фильтра
    $sostav_noperc = preg_replace(['~[^\pL\s,]+~us', '~-~'], ['', ' '], $sostav);
//  Длина
    $dlina = $document->find('.item_info_section')[0]->first('dl')->xpath('//dt')[3]->text();
    $dlina_result = preg_replace('/[^\d]+/', '', $dlina);
//  Вес
    $ves = $document->find('.item_info_section')[0]->first('dl')->xpath('//dt')[4]->text();
    $ves_result = preg_replace('/[^\d]+/', '', $ves);
//  Страна
    $country = $document->find('.item_info_section')[0]->first('dl')->xpath('//dt//strong')[5]->text();
```

**UPD**

Заметил, что такое происходит с сайтами, у которых доктайп *"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"*. Один ресурс, у которого *!DOCTYPE html и html lang="ru"* - данные в кириллице получает корректно

Comment: код и тестовый пример в студию

Comment: @teran обновил вопрос, спасибо

Comment: ну что, идей нет?..

Comment: Попробуйте mb_ereg_replace  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-ereg-replace.php ибо в PHP с Unicode не совсем комильфо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, дело было в кодировке страниц донора. Решением стало подключение третьего параметра в парсинг **'windows-1251'**:

```
$document = new Document('http://donor.ru/catalog/tovar/', true, 'windows-1251');
```